# Make a better implementation modifying ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list of hashmap.
One field is an Integer, and the other one is a Boolean which will tell me if that item is selected or not.

The final purpose is to change the ArrayList, unselected the old one item which was selected, and marking the new one. I made this piece of code, but I wich to know if there is a better way to do it.

```
VisualizationBean visualizationBean = new VisualizationBean();
ArrayList<HashMap<Boolean, Integer>> resultsPerPage = visualizationBean.getResultsPerPage();
for (Iterator iterator = resultsPerPage.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  HashMap<Boolean, Integer> hashMap = (HashMap<Boolean, Integer>) iterator.next();
   if(hashMap.containsKey(true)){
     int beforeSelected = hashMap.get("true");
     hashMap.put(false, beforeSelected);
   }
   else{
    if(hashMap.get(false) == number){
      hashMap.put(true, number);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't use a List of Maps to do what you are doing.

Use [`BitSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), it's designed for this exact purpose. (Depending on your requirements you may need a list of BitSets, but never a List of Maps, especially not from Boolean to anything).

Alternatively you could use a Map from Integer to Boolean (not from Boolean to Integer).

Comment: I was guessing that something like that must exist, but I didn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: and do you know how to mapmor initialize this field in faces-config.xml?? I was trying to find a way on internet, without success by this moment

Comment: @mujer sorry I know nothing about JSF. you should probably post a separate question

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare interfaces rather than concrete types, i.e. use `List` and `Map` rather than `ArrayList` and `HashMap`
2. `"true"` is clearly wrong - needs to be `true`, as the former is a String the latter a `Boolean`

As for the logic of your code, it would be easier for me to comment if you explained a bit more/better what you are trying to do.

Edit: If I understand what you're trying to do right, then I suggest that you have a new class, something like `SelectedItem` that has an `id` and a method called `isSelected()`. Then you'd call a method like `getItems(boolean selected)` or `getItems` on `VisualisationBean`. The former would give you only those items that are selected or not selected, the latter would give you all items and you would have to iterate through them to see which one is selected and which one is not. That type of change would make it feel more object-oriented rather than handling data structures.

Edit2: Or, depending on your needs, go with the suggestion made by @Sean Patrick Floyd

Answer (score 0):

Make a small helper class (In simplistic code)

```
class VisiblitySetting {
  public static int InvalidIndex = -1;
  public boolean IsSelectedNow;
  public boolean WasSelectedBefore;
  public int SelectionIndex;
}

ArrayList<int> wasselected = ...;
ArrayList<int> isnowselected = ...;
VisualizationBean visualizationBean = new VisualizationBean();
ArrayList<VisiblitySetting> resultsPerPage =  visualizationBean.getResultsPerPage();
for (Iterator iterator = resultsPerPage.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  VisiblitySetting vis = (VisiblitySetting) iterator.next();
  if(vis.IsSelectedNow){
   wasselected.add(vis.SelectionIndex);
   vis.IsSelected = false;
  }
  else if(vis.WasSelectedBefore){
   isnowselected.add(vis.SelectionIndex);
   vis.IsSelected = false;
  }
 }
}
```

But I might have missunderstood your code. Using a hash like that doesn't make much sense.